# MSSQL Bulk String to XML Insert Into

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Currently we import a table Import_File which has an Options column which has delimited values.
We need to load those delimited values to a different table.

Currently we do that one row at a time which tends to be slower as the number of rows can be 100k+

Is there a way to speed up the code below?

```
Declare @InvId uniqueidentifier
Declare @xml xml
Declare CurrFeatureList Cursor For
Select 
    import.InventoryId,
     N'<root><r><![CDATA[' + replace( import.OPTIONS ,',',']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r></root>'
From                Import_File import with (nolock)
Where
    import.options IS NOT NULL
    And ISNULL(import.IsFeatureProcessed,0) = 0
    And LEN(ISNULL(import.OPTIONS,''))>10
    And import.InventoryId Is Not Null

OPEN CurrFeatureList

FETCH NEXT FROM CurrFeatureList
INTO @InvId, @xml

Print 'Inventory Import #10000'
Print GetDate()
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

        Insert Into Import_File_Feature
        (
            FeatureId,
            InventoryId,
            FeatureText,
            FeatureGroup,
            FeatureCategory,
            FeatureIsAvailable,
            FeatureIsStandard
        )
        Select 
            NEWID(),
            @InvId,
            t.value('.','varchar(250)'),
            '',
            '',
            1,
            1
        From @xml.nodes('//root/r') as a(t)

        FETCH NEXT FROM CurrFeatureList
        INTO @InvId, @xml
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        Print 'Error    ' 
        Print @InvId 
        Print   ERROR_NUMBER() 
        Print   ERROR_SEVERITY()
        Print   ERROR_STATE()
        Print   ERROR_PROCEDURE()
        Print   ERROR_LINE()
        Print   ERROR_MESSAGE()

        FETCH NEXT FROM CurrFeatureList
        INTO @InvId, @xml
    END CATCH
END

Close CurrFeatureList
Deallocate CurrFeatureList
GO
```

Comment: Seems like the cursor could be replaced with `INSERT INTO SELECT` ...

Comment: Agree with @Rigerta. You're not doing anything in the cursor that really requires a cursor.

Comment: Yes, but I cant figure out how to do the select/joins in single statement. In theory yes, that sounds like the right approach but I havent played much with XML so not sure how to craft the SQL. Any recommendations on where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I have ever seen a cursor & TRY/CATCH block used for this kind of thing is for identifying and analyzing bad records while developing a new ETL process. If that's not what you're doing then the cursor is not required and will slow you down.

Let's review what you're doing:

1. You're pulling data into your cursor (CurrFeatureList) and turning Import_File.Options into an XML field so you can later use the XML NODES method to "split" your string.
2. Kick off the cursor
3. For each InventoryId you're:
   a. splitting the Import_File.Options into multiple rows
   b. inserting that InventoryId and associated rows into Import_File_Feature
   c. If there's an error you print it and move on to the next record

**What you should be doing**

Note how I split this string using XML nodes:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(100) = 'abc,cde,fff';

SELECT item = xxx.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM (VALUES (CAST(('<r>'+REPLACE(@x,',','</r><r>') +'</r>') AS xml))) x(xx)
CROSS APPLY xx.nodes('r') xxx(xxx);
```

**Results**

```
item
-----
abc
cde
fff
```

**OPTION 1**

Combine your initial join and subsequent XML/XML nodes splitter logic into one statement and do the insert:

```
WITH 
yourData AS
(
  Select 
      import.InventoryId,
       x = N'<r><![CDATA[' + replace( import.OPTIONS ,',',']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'
  From Import_File import with (nolock)
  Where
  import.options IS NOT NULL
  And ISNULL(import.IsFeatureProcessed,0) = 0
  And LEN(ISNULL(import.OPTIONS,''))>10
  And import.InventoryId Is Not Null
),
split AS
(
  SELECT InventoryId, item = i.value('.', 'varchar(8000)')
  FROM yourData
  CROSS APPLY x.nodes('r') s(i)  
)
Insert Into Import_File_Feature
(
  FeatureId,
  InventoryId,
  FeatureText,
  FeatureGroup,
  FeatureCategory,
  FeatureIsAvailable,
  FeatureIsStandard
 )
Select 
   newid(),
   import.InventoryId,
   item, -- this is the split out item from import.Options
    '',
    '',
    1,
    1
FROM split;
```

**OPTION 2**

Get a copy of [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and use it to do your splitting.

```
WITH split AS
(
  Select 
      import.InventoryId,
      import.OPTIONS
  From Import_File import with (nolock)
  CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(import.OPTIONS, ',')
  Where
  import.options IS NOT NULL
  And ISNULL(import.IsFeatureProcessed,0) = 0
  And LEN(ISNULL(import.OPTIONS,''))>10
  And import.InventoryId Is Not Null
)
Insert Into Import_File_Feature
(
  FeatureId,
  InventoryId,
  FeatureText,
  FeatureGroup,
  FeatureCategory,
  FeatureIsAvailable,
  FeatureIsStandard
 )
Select 
   newid(),
   import.InventoryId,
   item,
    '',
    '',
    1,
    1
FROM split
```

Note that, because I don't have any table definitions or sample data there was no way for me to test the code above.

Comment: There were two little change I had to make to get option 2 to work. 1) I had to cast import.OPTIONS to XML (currently they are varchar) 2) remove import.InventoryId and just keep it as InventoryId. Thank you for your help, that saved a lot of processing time and speed things up for me. The one scenario I am not a 100% sure about is handling exceptions when the varchar has xml characters like & or < or >. Any suggestions?